# Mahout seqdirectory not making a new file

Tags: sequence, mahout

I am trying to convert a text file into a sequence file that I can run mahout kmeans on. When I run the seqdirectory utility, I do not get any errors and it says that the program is completed. However, when I look in the output directory, it is empty. I've looked around and can't find any solutions to this. Thoughts?

Here is what I run in the terminal:
hduser@ubuntu:~$ $MAHOUT_HOME/bin/mahout seqdirectory --input Downloads/google/ --output Downloads/sparsefiles/ -c UTF-8

This is the output I get:
12/07/06 06:24:19 INFO driver.MahoutDriver: Program took 1091 ms (Minutes: 0.018183333333333333)

Comment: Which version of Mahout are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be producing the output on hdfs. Try checking:

```
hadoop dfs -ls Downloads/sparsefiles/
```

Also, to ensure it produces in your local filesystem you can modify the command like:

```
$MAHOUT_HOME/bin/mahout seqdirectory --input file://<home path>/Downloads/google/ --output file://<home path>/Downloads/sparsefiles/ -c UTF-8
```